# C# BackGroundWorker with ProgressBar Updates after process complete

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have the following in a button click event:

```
private void buttonSubmitAchChecks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) return;
  SubmittingAch(true);

  backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
  backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

  label_Status.Text = "Submitting checks to ACH ....";
  var qry = from ds in checkTrans.IndividualCheck
            where ds.SubmitToACH &&
                  ds.Status == "Entered" &&
                  ds.CheckAmount > 0 &&
                  ds.SubmitToACH
            select ds;

  if (qry.Count() <= 0)
  {
    label_Status.Text = "Nothing to submit. Check the Check Amount, ACH, and Status fields.";
  }
  else
  {
    progressBar1.Maximum = qry.Count();
    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    progressBar1.Step = 1;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(qry);
  }

}
```

My backgroundWorker1_DoWork:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
  {
    e.Cancel = true;
  }
  else
  {
    var qry = e.Argument as EnumerableRowCollection<CheckTrans.IndividualCheckRow>;
    if (qry != null)
    {
      Thread.Sleep(4000);

      //item.Status = ach.SubmitCheck(item);
      var ach = new SubmitAchChecks();
      foreach (var item in qry)
      {
        ach.SubmitCheck(item);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(1);
        Console.Write("backgroundWorker1_dowork=" + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "\r\n");
      }
    }

  }

}
```

My Cancel Button:

```
private void cancelAsyncButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
  {
    label_Status.Text = "Cancelling...";
    backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
  }
}
```

My backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Cancelled == true)
  {
    label_Status.Text = "Canceled!";
  }
  else if (e.Error != null)
  {
    label_Status.Text = "Error: " + e.Error.Message;
  }
  else
  {
    label_Status.Text = "Done!";
  }
  SubmittingAch(false);
}
```

My backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  progressBar1.Value += 1;
  Console.Write("progressbar1.value=" + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "\r\n");
}
```

I get following output in my debug window when I processed 2 items:

backgroundWorker1_dowork=0

backgroundWorker1_dowork=0

progressbar1.value=1

progressbar1.value=2

The event is firing, but as you can see from the console.write, it's happening AFTER the thread finishes. I get the progressbar scrolling, but only once the dowork has completed.

What have I done wrong on this? I'd like it to update as each item is completed.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your actual issue, but I noticed you're checking `ds.SubmitToACH` twice in your LINQ result `qry`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's due to the way threads work. `ProgressChange` is invoked on the UI thread using `BeginInvoke`, and therefore on another thread. Meanwhile, the worker thread continues running. Since there is not much work to do, the `BackgroundWorker` finishes its work before `BeginInvoke` actually invokes the method, because thread switches don't happen every CPU operation. They happen after quite a few. To avoid this, manually call the method that increments the `ProgressBar`'s value using `this.Invoke()`.

Comment: This was what I neeed! Thank you! For those searching, here is a link to the invoke on Microsoft's site where I used their example and it worked perfectly:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx

Comment: Tried this and pretty much every answer I've found on here and still no joy.  My progress bar just waits until the worker thread has finished and then boom - it updates.

Comment: @Bertie: That has two likely causes: either the UI thread is also doing work, or progress isn’t being reported. You can differentiate the two by trying to interact with the UI. Do other buttons on the form respond while you expect the progress bar to be moving? The window controls? Once you’ve figured that out, a good next step would be to use a debugger: breakpoint on progress reporting in the latter case, pause during the work to find out what the main thread is doing in the former.

Comment: @Ry- After a lot of jigging around - basically doing what you suggested, i still had the same result. The progress was being reported, buttons and window controls were responsive, debug proved everything wws being called there and then. Now, i had my logic in a separate method to DoWork. As a last resort i cut and pasted the code into the DoWork method, compiled, ran ... Bob's your uncle it updated as it should. I moved it back into its own method and it stopped working again. Basically, the code HAD to be in the DoWork method.